# How to join 2 table if the second table has no matching information

Tags: mysql, sql

Hy, i have a table like this :

```
Table colors :
----------------------------
| colorsid   code    name  |
----------------------------
|   1         aaa    yellow|
|   2         bbb    red   |
|   3         ccc    green |
----------------------------

Table pictures :
---------------------------
| picid   file    typeid  |
---------------------------
|   5     ooo.png    1    |
|   6     ccc.jpg    2    |
---------------------------
```

Result should like this :

```
------------------------------------------------------
| colorsid   code    name     picid   file     typeid|
------------------------------------------------------
|   1         aaa    yellow     5      ooo.png    1  |
|   2         bbb    red        6      ccc.png    2  |
|   3         ccc    green                           |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to use sql join (left,right,cross,inner) but the result always showing 2 record. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: why would the cross join not show 6?

Comment: Your tables appear to have matching information `colorsid` and `typeid`.  You should clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify the above:

`JOIN`, by itself, is synonymous with `*INNER* JOIN`. The result is to consist only of *matching* rows. Only rows which have a value in *both* tables will be returned.

There are, however, two flavors of `*OUTER* JOIN`:   `LEFT`, and `RIGHT`.

In this case, *all* of the rows from the table (the table on the `LEFT` side, or the one on the `RIGHT` side, of the `JOIN` ...) will be included in the result set. Values from the other-side table will be included *if* a matching row exists in that table; otherwise, the values in those columns will be `NULL`.

This seems to be *exactly* what you're looking for here ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM colors
LEFT JOIN pictures ON
colors.id = pictures.typeid
```